# SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder" in Scala IDE

Tags: eclipse, scala, apache-spark

I am developing a scala code to read ascii delimited file and create Parquet output file. 
Below is my code

```
val FileDF = spark.read
    .option("sep",delimiter) 
    .schema(FinalSchema)
    .csv(inputfilepath)

val FileDF = datasetnew.withColumn("ColFileName", lit(filename))

val query = dataframefinal.write
    .mode("overwrite")
    .format("parquet")
    .save(outputfilepath)
```

When I run above code I got

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
```

In Eclipse at least output is generated where as in putty when I run with spark-submit in cluster mode spark job is failing without any output.

Comment: See [PARQUET-369](https://issues-test.apache.org/jira/browse/PARQUET-369).

Comment: we are using spark 2.10 in CDH 5.10 cluster. The mentioned bug is already resolved as per jira issue